# SQL Server produces different results with and without Order By

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to include ROW_NUMBER with ORDER BY but it's not working as expected. I tried using ORDER BY (without the ROW_NUMBER) and the results with and without ORDER BY are different (even the number of rows is different).

Here is the complete query (I know it's not the best query):

```
WITH cte1
AS
(   
    SELECT t1.OrderNo, t1.BlockID, t1.PcbID AS 'TopPcbID', t3.PcbID AS 'MountedOn', 
        t3.TimeDone AS TimeEnd, t9.TimeDone, t7.McID, t8.DeviceID, t8.Program, t6.CurMcID, t9.DeviceID AS D1, t9.Program AS P1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t3.PcbID, t7.McID ORDER BY t9.TimeDone DESC) RN
    FROM PanelBlockTrace t1
        INNER JOIN (SELECT PcbID, MIN(BlockNo) AS 'MINIM' FROM PanelBlockTrace
            GROUP BY PcbID) t2 ON t1.PcbID = t2.PcbID
        INNER JOIN PcbTrace t3 ON t1.PcbID = t3.PcbID OR 
            (CASE WHEN t1.BlockNo = 0 THEN t1.BlockID ELSE t1.PcbID END) = t3.PcbID
        INNER JOIN (SELECT PcbID, MAX(McID) AS 'MAXIM' FROM PcbTrace
            WHERE Program NOT LIKE 'PANEL%' GROUP BY PcbID) t4 ON t3.PcbID = t4.PcbID
        INNER JOIN LineDesc t5 ON t3.McID = t5.McID
        INNER JOIN (SELECT LineID, MAX(McID) AS 'CurMcID' FROM LineDesc WHERE McID NOT LIKE '%9' GROUP BY LineID) t6 ON t5.LineID = t6.LineID
        INNER JOIN LineDesc t7 ON t5.LineID = t7.LineID
        LEFT JOIN PcbTrace t8 ON t3.PcbID = t8.PcbID AND t7.McID = t8.McID
        LEFT JOIN PcbTrace t9 ON t8.DeviceID IS NULL 
            AND t9.TimeDone BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(date, t3.TimeDone)) AND t3.TimeDone
            AND t9.McID = CurMcID AND t9.McID = t7.McID
    WHERE (t1.BlockID IN (...) OR t1.PcbID IN (...))
        AND t1.BlockNo = t2.MINIM
        AND t1.BlockID != t1.PcbID
        AND t1.PcbID != ''
        AND t3.Program NOT LIKE 'PANEL%'
        AND t3.McID = t4.MAXIM
),
cte11
AS
(
    SELECT * FROM cte1
    WHERE RN <= 3
),
cte12
AS
(
    SELECT t1.OrderNo, t1.BlockID, t1.TopPcbID, t1.MountedOn, t1.TimeEnd, LEAD(t1.TimeDone,2) OVER(ORDER BY t1.MountedOn) AS T1, 
        t1.McID, t1.DeviceID, t1.Program, t1.D1, t1.P1, t2.CurMcID, t1.RN
    FROM cte11 t1
        INNER JOIN
            (SELECT t1.MountedOn,t1.McID,t1.P1,t1.Program,MAX(RN) AS LastRec, t1.CurMcID-1 AS CurMcID 
            FROM cte11 t1
                LEFT JOIN (SELECT MountedOn,McID,Program,P1 FROM cte11 WHERE RN = 1) t2 ON
                    t1.MountedOn = t2.MountedOn AND t1.McID = t2.McID AND (t1.Program = t2.Program OR t1.P1 = t2.P1)
            WHERE RN <= 3
            GROUP BY t1.MountedOn, t1.McID, t1.P1, t1.Program, t1.CurMcID) t2 ON 
                t1.MountedOn = t2.MountedOn AND t1.McID = t2.McID 
                AND (t1.RN = t2.LastRec OR t1.RN = 1)

),
cte2
AS
(
    SELECT t1.*,t2.DeviceID AS D2, t2.Program AS P2, t2.TimeDone AS T2
    FROM cte12 t1
        LEFT JOIN PcbTrace t2 ON t1.DeviceID IS NULL AND t1.D1 IS NULL AND t1.McID = t1.CurMcID AND t1.McID = t2.McID
            AND t2.TimeDone BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(date, t1.T1)) AND t1.T1 

)
SELECT * FROM cte2
```

Anyway, this is where things get weird.

The end goal is to include ROW_NUMBER:

```
cte2
AS
(
    SELECT t1.*,t2.DeviceID AS D2, t2.Program AS P2, t2.TimeDone AS T2, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MountedOn, t1.McID ORDER BY t2.TimeDone) RN2
    FROM cte12 t1
        LEFT JOIN PcbTrace t2 ON t1.DeviceID IS NULL AND t1.D1 IS NULL AND t1.McID = t1.CurMcID AND t1.McID = t2.McID
            AND t2.TimeDone BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(date, t1.T1)) AND t1.T1 

)
SELECT * FROM cte2
```

Since adding ROW_NUMBER produces completely different result (without ROW_NUMBER: 3762 rows, with ROW_NUMBER: 17 rows), I tried simplifying the last part and figured that ORDER BY is the cause.

```
cte2
AS
(
    SELECT t2.DeviceID AS Device2, t2.Program AS Program2, t2.TimeDone AS Time2
    FROM cte12 t1
        LEFT JOIN PcbTrace t2 ON t1.DeviceID IS NULL AND t1.D1 IS NULL AND t1.McID = t1.CurMcID AND t1.McID = t2.McID
            AND t2.TimeDone BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(date, t1.T1)) AND t1.T1 

)
SELECT * FROM cte2
```

The result without ORDER BY (first 10 out of **3762** rows):

```
Device2 Program2    Time2
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
1557852877  G8542G004MPB_4M3_00 2019-05-15 00:01:59.777
1557852877  G8542G004MPB_4M3_00 2019-05-15 00:04:56.790
1557852877  G8542G004MPB_4M3_00 2019-05-15 00:05:42.843
```

Code with ORDER BY:

```
cte2
AS
(
    SELECT t2.DeviceID AS Device2, t2.Program AS Program2, t2.TimeDone AS Time2
    FROM cte12 t1
        LEFT JOIN PcbTrace t2 ON t1.DeviceID IS NULL AND t1.D1 IS NULL AND t1.McID = t1.CurMcID AND t1.McID = t2.McID
            AND t2.TimeDone BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(date, t1.T1)) AND t1.T1 

)
SELECT * FROM cte2
ORDER BY Time2
```

Result (first 10 out of **17** rows):

```
Device2 Program2    Time2
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Note:

1. This cte is the actually the fourth cte and is using the result of another cte (cte12). I'm not sure how this might affect the result.
2. There's no ddl because I'm pulling data from existing database and it'll be too complicated to simulate that many tables.
3. And yes, the only difference between the last two queries is the ORDER BY clause, and yet the number of rows returned is different (3762 vs 17)

Edit:

1. If I simply use TOP (say TOP 10000), the result will be as expected, 3762 rows. But if the TOP number is too large (anything more than TOP 27415), it'll revert back to 17 rows
2. Somehow it works as expected (3762 rows) if I change the time constraints from

   t2.TimeDone BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,CONVERT(date, t1.T1)) AND t1.T1

   to

   t2.TimeDone BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,-1,t1.T1) AND t1.T1

Comment: what do you mean by `results are different` ? No of rows return are different ?

Comment: yes, no of rows are different (3762 vs 17)

Comment: please show the complete query. Without it we can't determine the issue

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify `ORDER BY`, SQL Server is free to return the results in any order that is convenient.  You could theoretically run the same query dozens of times it could produce a different order every time.

But it will always return the same rows, unless you are using `TOP`.

---

More after seeing entire query:

In your first CTE we see

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY t9.TimeDone DESC) RN
```

and in the second CTE we see

```
   SELECT * FROM cte1
    WHERE RN <= 3
```

Now imagine SQL Server is generating the results for the first CTE.   It is first asked to order those values by `TimeDone desc`, and then assign row numbers to the results. Consider the case where there are multiple rows with the same `TimeDone` value.  It must put values with higher TimeDone before lower values, but for the rows with the same value, it can put those rows in any order that is convenient.  Then you filter out just the first 3 rows.  (This is a tricky way of doing the same as `TOP`!).

Let's say you have a table like this:

```
ID  Time 
A   05:00
B   04:00
C   03:00
D   03:00
E   02:00
F   01:00
```

You ask SQL Server to order these by `Time desc`, and assign a row number to each.  There are two possible results.

```
A  05:00  1
B  04:00  2
C  03:00  3
D  03:00  4
E  03:00  5
F  01:00  6
```

or

```
A  05:00  1
B  04:00  2
D  03:00  3        // <-- C and D
C  03:00  4        //     are swapped
E  03:00  5
F  01:00  6
```

Both fulfill the rule of placing higher values of Time before lower values.  When the values are the same, it's up to SQL Server to choose as it finds convenient.

But if you filter these results on `RN <= 3`, you will end up with two different results.

If you then take these two results and feed them into more and more complex CTEs, you may end up with completely different answers.

Every time you change the overall query by adding TOP with different values, or ORDER BY, SQL Server may generate a completely different execution plan to find the results.

Even if you never changed the query or the data, it could generate different results depending on other environmental factors.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. I'm not using TOP at all but the result is different. I understand that the result can be different, but the number of rows returned should definitely be the same and that is exactly the problem.

Comment: You have only posted partial queries, no ddl, and no sample data. The 2 partial queries that you did post are exactly the same except for the order by clause. Either you posted something incorrectly or something very important is missing. And despite your focus on ROW_NUMBER, it is absent entirely from what you posted, so your situation is not clear.

Comment: But I'll add that in my case, TimeDone is very very unlikely to have overlap records since it's down to millisecond.

Comment: Perhaps you could check.  You might be surprised. ;)